# Make a local oracle DB from server

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL Developer, I connect to my friend's DB and use it. Now I want to have a copy of this DB on my own PC to change it and test something. I installed Oracle. now how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of Oracle Datapump.

Note. Oracle uses the term "schema" where for example mysql uses the term "database".

At your friend site:

```
expdp userid=system directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=myschema.dmp logfile=expdp_myschema.log schemas=MYSCHEMA
```

At your site:

```
impdp userid=system directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=myschema.dmp logfile=impdp_myschema.log
```

Best of luck,

Bjarte

Comment: site? what's site? I am using Oracle in an application with sql developer, I exported his DB, now what should i do? i am using sql developer and oracle 11g express

Comment: In this context: "your friend site" is your friend computer. "your site" is your computer. But I understand you are looking for a SQL Developer approach to export and import. SQL Developer integrates with datapump. Youtube is your friend: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cs9i8kp9FKY

Comment: Thanks comrade, I Export the Database and create a new database in my own PC, then run the exported file. (All done by SqlDeveloper). Thanks for your help and care.